# pdftex maxing out my CPU on Mac

Tags: pdftex, mactex, sublime-text

First, some info on my system:

```
Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)
MacTex 2013 Distribution (http://tug.org/mactex/)
Using Latexing package in Sublime Text 3 (might be relevant)
Skim pdf viewer (as per the Latexing setup tutorial)
```

By chance I opened my Activity Monitor today and found four *pdftex* processes running, using between 90-100% CPU (my battery consumption was oddly high, that's why I checked). Sublime Text with opened tex files, but I wasn't using them or compiling them at the moment.

I closed both the Sublime Text and Skim, but the processes didn't quit. I had to quit them manually.

Anyone experienced this before? Any thoughts on what I could do to prevent this from repeating?

//edit
I opened Sublime Text again and tried compiling a document. pdftex process didn't appear in Activity Monitor. My theory atm is that it was a remnant of me trying other editors (TeXWorks, TeXShop)... Thoughts?

Comment: I just wanted to add that I have had the same issue with the TeXpad app. There was a mistake in my LaTeX code (missing brace) and the compiling process would simply not complete. I forced the app to quit, but the `texpdf` process still remained active. I only realised this later when my MacBook Pro starting fanning for no apparent reason.

Comment: I still had the same issue after fixing the error in tex file. I had to delete `.aux` , `.log`, .`synctex` and `.toc` files in my project.

Answer (score 9):

I have had the same problem. In my case there was an error in my TikZ code (forgotten semicolon), which made the compiler run indefinitely. When you hit "ESC" in sublime, the compiling process does NOT get stopped, Sublime only hides the little window on the bottom. To actually cancel the compilation progress out of sublime you have to hit CMB+B again. The window on the bottom will then say

```
### Got request to terminate compilation ###

[User terminated compilation process]
```

and you don't have lonely pdftex processes maxing out your cpu in the background.

Hope this helps.

Edit: I just read that you are using LaTeXing package. I use LaTeX Tools, so my Sublime might behave a little different.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I think that may be the case actually. I had a few problems few days back when my compiler got stuck. But I thought quitting Sublime would help. Apparently it didn't. Anyway, will keep an eye on that! Thanks again :)

Comment: Sounds like a bug in sublime: Hiding a process from the user that can potentially consume large resources.