# pdftex maxing out my CPU on Mac with texmaker

Tags: texmaker

pdftex is maxing out my CPU on mac. I am using Texmaker. This is similar to

[pdftex maxing out my CPU on Mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145617/pdftex-maxing-out-my-cpu-on-mac)

Is there a way to terminate the pdftex process in Texmaker?

Comment: To terminate the process, open the activity monitor, mark the selected process and click on `Force a process to quit`. However this questions seems better suited for apple.stackexchange.

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: Or `pkill pdftex` on the command line, assuming Macs have `pkill` (which I would guess they do, but Apple does strange things).

Comment: I think your question is rather: how can I terminate the pdftex process in Texmaker, correct?

Comment: Thanks @samcarter! I am terminating the process in the activity monitor now.  @ShreevatsaR: Yes, it would be easier to end it in Texmaker.